# SolrNet : How do I search a Multi-valued Field in Solr?

Tags: search, solr, solrnet

I am using SolrNet and my schema looks something like the following:

```
<int name="prodId">Id</prodid>
<str name="prodname">Name</prodname>
<arr name="categories"><str>Cat1</str><str>Cat2</str></categories
....
</doc>
```

Now I want to perform a search by Category. That is retrieve product whose category collection has "Cat1" for example. Please let me know how I can do this using SolrNet. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to do anything special for searching a multivalued field. The following should work just fine:

```
var query = new SolrQueryByField("categories","Cat1");
```

or

```
var query = new SolrQuery("categories:Cat1");
```

Comment: @Cook, I tried that and the final url looked like the following: http://localhost:8983/solr/core0//select?q=(categories:Cat1) But it didn't retrieve any results, if I change the url to query prodname, it works.

Comment: How is your categories field defined in your schema.xml file? It needs to have `indexed="true"` set in order to search against it.

Comment: Here is what it looks like in schema.xml: <field name="categories" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" required="false" />

Comment: Ok, the field definition looks good. It feels like something is not right with the Solr instance and not SolrNet. Can you change the url to http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?q=categories%3ACat1 or http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select?q=categories%3A%22Cat1%22 and get any results.

Comment: Also, just looked at the Solr example site that has a features field set to `multiValued=true` and they are using a field type of text_general instead of string, so you may want to switch to that field type as it will be a more flexible field to search against b/c of the differences between it and the string field type. You will need to reindex your data if you change the field type in order to see the change reflected in the results.

Comment: @cook I tried those url but I still didn't get any result. I guess I will change the field type as you suggested and see whether it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 if this doesn't work you @Raza it's likely a field type issue.